# vertical line tkinter using grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a vertical line between two columns using tkinter grid. I have been looking for ways to do it, but it's all something that I don't need like coordinates.

```
from tkinter import *   
master = Tk()
player1 = "A"
player2 = "B"
from tkinter import *
Label(master, text="NAME", font=30).grid(row=0)
Label(master, text=player1, font=30).grid(row=1)
Label(master, text=player2, font=30).grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="SCORE", font=30).grid(column=2, row=0)
```

I want to add a vertical line at column 1, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a [`ttk.Separator`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Separator.html) widget.

Add the following to your code:

```
import tkinter.ttk

tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky='ns')
```

Here `rowspan=3` is necessary to make the separator span all 3 rows (the header, player 1 and player2). The `sticky='ns'` is there to stretch the separator from the top to the bottom of the window. Separators are only 1 pixel long per default, so without the `sticky` it would hardly be visible.

Preview of the result:

[image: Preview]

Comment: there was an error that said:  "NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined" when i copied and pasted it into my project

Comment: @toto1105 Did you include the `import tkinter.ttk`?

Comment: no, i just changed it. Now it says that 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'ttk'

Comment: i just changed some things and its fine now! thanks for the help @Aran-Fey

Comment: "changed some things"  please let us know what you changed so others can benefit

Comment: @toto1105 you have created tk with some other name, eg root maybe

Comment: Python 3.6, Ubuntu 18.4.: I had to use sticky='nse'. If e(ast) is not given, the separation line runs through the mid of column.